# SwiftUI - Using Navigation View and Sheets correctly

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, navigationlink

Having issues with a NavigationView and Sheet. I have the below flow:
- ContentView: Has button that opens ContentView2 sheet 
- ContentView2: Has NavigationLink with header that goes to ContentView3 
- ContentView3: Has NavigationLink, no header, that directs users to ContentView2

However, when I set up the above flow, I end up getting stacked headers when users go back and forth between ContentView2 and ContentView3. How would I prevent this and only have 1 header when users go back and forth between the two views? Thanks!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Click"){
            self.showSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            ContentView2()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView3()){
                Text("Click Here")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Bar Title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView3: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2()){
            Text("Click Here")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need only one `NavigationView` in root, so here is corrected components

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Click"){
            self.showSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
           NavigationView {    // only here !!
            ContentView2()
           }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView2: View {
    var body: some View {
         NavigationLink(destination: ContentView3()){
             Text("Click Here")
         }
         .navigationBarTitle("Bar Title", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: having a navigation button item does not work in the sheet.